# Ansible-vault doesn't work with --vault-password-file

Tags: ansible

for some kind of yml files that we have to store passwords (of MySQL users) we use ansible-vault encrypt to maintain some security.

The problem is every time we have to edit we are forced to input the password.

I was looking how to fix this and seems is pretty easy but I couldn't make it work yet.

I've created a file in my home directory called:

```
.vault_pass.txt
```

inside of that, I have the password. And in the ansible.cfg in my repository I have the variable:

```
vault_password_file = ~/.vault_pass.txt
```

Didn't work as expected. So I tried to force ansible-vault command to read the file with this parameter

```
# ansible-vault decrypt --vault-password-file ~/.vault_pass.txt vars/vars-mysql-config.yml
```

Output error:

```
ERROR! input is not vault encrypted data for vars/vars-mysql-config.yml
```

It seems I forgot something here but I wasn't able to find the right info.

Anyone has any idea about that?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47636383/ansible-dynamically-prompt-vault-password-when-needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you misuse `decrypt` command instead of `view`.

To view encrypted file use `view`:

```
ansible-vault view --vault-password-file ~/.vault_pass.txt vars/vars-mysql-config.yml
```

If you want to decrypt the file and leave it in plain text, use `decrypt`:

```
ansible-vault decrypt --vault-password-file ~/.vault_pass.txt vars/vars-mysql-config.yml
```

If you try to run `decrypt` command second time, it will give you expected error:

> ERROR! input is not vault encrypted data for vars/vars-mysql-config.yml

because file is already plain-texted.

Comment: This is still giving me this error: 
`ERROR! input is not vault encrypted data. main.yml is not a vault encrypted file for main.yml` - my file is a standard yaml file with an encrypted string in it - do I have to use a different command to view the details of the encrypted string?